# Django: How to use OuterRef() for .get() in annotate?

Tags: django, django-treebeard

I am using `django-treebeard` and use a model that allows recursive relations.

So, I need to count the number of my descendants using `.annotate()`, but
To get it, you need to go through `.get()` once, as shown below.

However, in that case, `OuterRef("pk")` does not seem to work and the following error occurs.
`This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

What can I do to solve this problem?

```py
class Comment(MP_Node):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField( max_length=1000)
    commented_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="replies",
    )
```

```py
queryset.filter(post=post)
.annotate(
    reply_count=Count(
        Comment.objects.get(
            pk=OuterRef("pk")
        ).get_descendants()
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share the `get_descendants()` method (and perhaps the entire `Comment` model.

Comment: The `get_descendants()` thing is defined in `django-treebeard`, so I don't know what it does internally.